# drag drop not working in website

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

When i try to use drag and drop in jquery when i run it is not working in my project ,but when i copy the same html in fiddle it is working for me.Please help me why it is not working in my project but when i take same code to fiddle it starts working.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
            <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
            <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

 $(function () {
                    $("#droppable").droppable({
                        stop: function (event, ui) {
                            alert('drop');
                        }
                    });

                    $(".draggable").draggable({
                        containment: 'document',
                        cursor: 'move',
                        revert: "invalid",

                    });
                    $(".droppable_widget,.draggable_widget").sortable({
                        connectWith: ".droppable_widget,.draggable_widget",
                        start: function (event, ui) {
                        },
                        stop: function (event, ui) {
                            var item = $(ui.item);

                            var to = item.parent().is(".droppable_widget");
                            var siblingsCount = item.siblings().size();
                            if (to && siblingsCount > 0) {
                                alert("only one item allowed here");
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    $(".connectedSortable").sortable({
                        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
                    }).disableSelection;

                });




<div style="width: 50%; padding-left: 15px; padding-top: 15px; float: left;">
                                        <div id="users"><div class="draggable_widget ui-sortable"><ul class="connectedSortable ui-sortable" id="T1" style="">Team#0<li>1</li><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>2</li></ul></div><div class="draggable_widget ui-sortable"><ul class="connectedSortable ui-sortable" id="T2" style="">Team#1<li style="" class="">2</li><li>2</li></ul></div></div>

                                    </div>
<td class="tcol cnt"> <div><p id="H1">1</p><div style="height:100px;background-color:aqua;width:100px;" class="droppable_widget"></div><br><p id="H1">1A</p><div style="height:100px;background-color:aqua;width:100px;" class="droppable_widget"></div><br></div></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace **//** with **http://** or **https://**

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Change Above Code with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: are you sure you replaced all `//` with `http://` also put your javascript code between `<script>` tag

Comment: yes i am sure..i have replaced all things as you suggested.http://jsfiddle.net/tBaHd/5/    this is the fiddle that i have created and its working here

Comment: Check the link i have mentioned above. Is it working?

Comment: What's the problem with my code?Please let me know..i think its the sorting only working  that is also working for me too...try to drag the team in colored div..i.e not working

Comment: There is no probem in your code. If you go to this link http://www.hlinker.com/aaaa/index.html its working fine. Just copy the  source code and use in your page. I also tried dragging team1 and team2 and its working great. Check if you are using latest broswer

Comment: what the problem i am facing is that i a m creating teams dynamically..after all the html is created in browser it is not working there but when i copy the dynamic created html in fiddle it works there..i am not able to get what's the problem there